# Application crash when acess database

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

In my application I access database in background and send data to server. To do so, we use `NSThread` method

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(repeatedMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

This results in application crash with following error :
 `malloc: error for object 0xc53c200: double free set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

Comment: this happens when you release some variable(most probably a class level variable) twice. Probably it has nothing to do with thread. check the variables you release in repeatedMethod and make sure you various threads are not releasing same variable at same time.